# Kubernetes and failover service

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, failover

I have next situation and I am not sure if it is possible to achieve it using kubernetes only.

There are two pods, one with live service is available on e.g. givemedata.example.com, temporary one on givemedata2.example.com. Temporary one is without any dependency and there just to allow some long term jobs to continue run while real one is down for maintenance.

Cluster is on GKE.

I need to setup failover so that if live one is down for maintenance, failover should redirect calls to temporary one.

Main reason is to use only one endpoint, e.g. givemedata.example.com.

My question is if this is possible and how to do it?

Comment: Did you consider using Ingress for load balancing:  https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer ?

Comment: @Malgorzata I do not see failover in document you added in comment.

Comment: This is example which show how redirect traffic to backends - in your case you can define one host - givemedata.example.com and two backends. As you wanted to achieve - to use only one endpoint.

Comment: What kind of LoadBalancer are you using - GCE -http or L4 network loabalancera with ingress ?

Comment: @Malgorzata currently there is no load balancer, as we we do not have two services yet running. problem is also that this is not HTTP protocol, but GRPC, still it should not be problem for setup. I do not need load balancing but failover on two different kubernetes pods.

Comment: Can you provide all specification you have used/files and configuration - please paste them to post?

Comment: I cannot share anything as there is not failover now.

Comment: I was speaking about config files/services, tutorial you have used so far to set up your applications. Please provide this information and post them to your question as well as these on you have provided in comments -   that you are using GRPC protocol.

Comment: @Malgorzata maybe my question is wide. If so, please let me know and I will delete it. I do not have any files to provide, as I do not know where to look for solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [NGINX  ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/). Add
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet:` annotation to ingress configuration file and add block of code which will check if domain is available, if not it will redirect traffic to different one.

Thanks to this annotation it is possible to add custom configuration in the server configuration block.

Read more: [server snippet](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet).

Remember to add this server to `nginx.conf` file in **/etc/nginx** directory.
Here is example cofiguration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: my-ingress
 namespace: ingress-nginx
 annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url : "true"
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      set $agentflag 0;  
      if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Mobile)" ){  
      set $agentflag 1;  
      }  
      if ( $agentflag = 1 ) {  
      return 301 https://givemedata2.example.com;  
      }
spec:
 rules:
 - host: givemedata.example.com
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /
       backend:
         serviceName: service-name
         servicePort: service-port
```

Comment: Is this going to be failover or redirect service? Because same hostname should be kept, so I want givemedata.example.com to be endpoint always.

Comment: It is just an example, if endpoint givemedata.example.com will be unavailable traffic will be redirect to givemedata2.example.com. But by default whole traffic will be send to givemedata.example.com.